# Duvida Select / PHP

Tags: php, firebird

Eu estou fazendo um `select` desta forma.

```
$stmt = $lokos->prepare("select CODIGO_PROGRAMA, VERSAO_PROGRAMA,
                         DATA_INSERCAO, DESCRICAO_ALTERACAO from
                         programas_padrao Order by DESCRICAO_ALTERACAO DESC");
```

Este select ele irá puxar todos os dados que tem no meu baco de dados.

ex:  PROGRAMA 1, PROGRAMA 2, PROGRAMA3

Como eu faço para o meu `select` ou através de um `if` exibir somente a mais recente ao invés de exibir PROGRAMA1, PROGRAMA 2 e o 3?

**Como eu faço para ele exibir somente o 3?**

---

Esse é o código Original. O qual não estou conseguindo fazer.

```
<?php

$user = "SYSDBA";
$pass = "masterkey";
try{
    $lokos=new PDO("firebird:localhost=127.0.0.1;dbname=DUOSIG_APLICACAO",$user,$pass);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Falha na conexão.".$e->getcode();
}

$stmt = $lokos->prepare("select CODIGO_PROGRAMA, VERSAO_PROGRAMA, DATA_INSERCAO, DESCRICAO_ALTERACAO from programas_padrao Order by DESCRICAO_ALTERACAO DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$dados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($dados as $row) {
   echo "<li class='nome'>{$row->CODIGO_PROGRAMA} </li> ";
 echo "<li class='versao'>{$row->VERSAO_PROGRAMA} </li> ";
echo "<li class='data'>{$row->DATA_INSERCAO} </li> ";
echo "<li class='descricao'><p>{$row->DESCRICAO_ALTERACAO} </p> </li> ";
}

?>
```

Comment: faz where no codigo do programa 3, ou coloca um campo de data faz where com a data

Comment: Para limitar o número de registro, use `LIMIT X`, onde `X` é a quantidade desejada. O resto depende qual é sua condição de *mais recente*. Se for o último inserido, você deve ordernar de forma decrescente pelo `id` usando `ORDER BY id DESC`; se for o último registro modificado, você precisa armazenar a data de modificação em uma coluna (tipo `updated_at`) e fazer `ORDER BY updated_at DESC`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Seu comentário é uma resposta a esta questão.

Comment: @Ismael, é possível, eu não entendi bem se esse é exatamente o problema do autor. E ainda depende da informação sobre qual é a codição para definir o registro mais recente. Assim que o autor especificar isso, será possível responder de forma completa.

Comment: Esse "exibir somente o 3": você deseja que ele exiba apenas 3 resultados ou que ele mostra apenas o terceiro programa?

Comment: No caso o seguinte. Tenho vários resultados , pense o seguinte  EU TENHO    1 CARRO COR CINZA E O CARRO COR VERMELHO BLZ ?,  No carro Cinza eu tenho uma porta versão, 1,2 e o 3 , E no carro vermelho eu tenho também a versão 1,2 e o 3, BLZ ?. Eu entro no painel e posto, VERSÃO 1 , 2, E O 3 do carro cinza. E no mesmo dia eu posto  a Versao 1, 2 e o 3 do carro vermelho. Ao invés de ficar todas as versões postadas eu quero que apareça apenas AS VERSÕES finais ou seja, CARRO VERMELHO -> 3 , CARRO CINZA -> 3, ao invés de aparecer tudo.

Comment: A pergunta se aplica ao firebird certo? ou é mysql mesmo?

Comment: Apenas ao firebird